# Arrow's impossibility theorem implications

Tags: economics, decision-theory, voting-theory

If we knew that in an unfair voting system (ie: it is known that IIA does not hold) then if (1) holds, how would we go about inferring that (2) holds and then is it possible to show that if (1) and (2) hold , it implies (3)?

1) There is no "dictator": no single voter possesses the power to always determine the group's preference.

2) If every voter's preference between X and Y remains unchanged, then the group's preference between X and Y will also remain unchanged (even if voters' preferences between other pairs like X and Z, Y and Z, or Z and W change).

3)If every voter prefers alternative X over alternative Y, then the group prefers X over Y.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how 1) could possibly imply 2). 1) is a rather weak premise, and 2) is quite a strong result -- I'd expect that it should be easy to produce a counterexample in which 1) holds and 2) doesn't.

Comment: Isn't there a theorem, that it is impossoble to habe 1, 2, and 3 at the same time?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is: Arrow's impossibility theorem, i.e. the thing in the title. So I suspect the question hasn't been written properly.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Possibly the question was supposed to be to show that (1) and (2) imply the negation of (3). If so, it’s worth noting that the Wikipedia article on Arrow’s theorem includes a decent sketch of a proof.

Comment: @Semiclassical the question is not wrong (I mentioned that the voting system is known to be unfair perhaps I should clarify that in such a system IIA does not hold)

Comment: @joriki hmm.. but if there is no dictator, then does it not imply that there is no pivotal voter that can cause the social outcome to be different than the initial state as eg: under majority rule, there will never be enough majority to overturn the initial group consensus

Comment: I don't understand why you think that I'd spend time answering that question when Brian has already posted a link to counterexamples. Ping me again when you've disproved the counterexamples.

Comment: If rejecting IIA is what you mean by 'unfair', that's fine. But this amounts to rejecting condition (2). It is in this sense that your question makes no sense as written.

Answer (score 1):

(1) does not imply (2), and (1) and (2) together do not imply (3). There are many non-dictatorial methods that fail to satisfy (2); see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_of_irrelevant_alternatives). For a simple method that satisfies (1) and (2) but not three, let $u$ and $v$ be two designated voters. If $u$ and $v$ have the same preferences, their preferences are adopted by society; if not, [range voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_voting) is used. There is no dictator, and (2) is satisfied, but (3) clearly is not.